# Facebook conceal native crash not getting to the app

Tags: android, exception, facebook-conceal

I'm using Facebook Conceal v2.0.1 library in my app and sometimes I get the following native crash when I try to decrypt an image (jpg):

```
10-19 15:57:42.885 19174-19174/? A/fbassert: Assert (/Users/heliosalonso/github/helios175/conceal/first-party/fbjni/native/fb/jni/Exceptions.cpp:308): ptr

                                             --------- beginning of crash
10-19 15:57:42.886 19174-19174/? A/libc: Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 2, fault addr 0xdeadb00c in tid 19174 (.atheer.airflow)

                                         [ 10-19 15:57:42.887   368:  368 W/         ]
                                         debuggerd: handling request: pid=19174 uid=10278 gid=10278 tid=19174

10-19 15:57:42.985 19268-19268/? A/DEBUG: *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
10-19 15:57:42.985 19268-19268/? A/DEBUG: Build fingerprint: 'samsung/gts28vewifixx/gts28vewifi:7.0/NRD90M/T713XXU2BQD3:user/release-keys'
10-19 15:57:42.985 19268-19268/? A/DEBUG: Revision: '5'
10-19 15:57:42.985 19268-19268/? A/DEBUG: ABI: 'arm'
10-19 15:57:42.985 19268-19268/? A/DEBUG: pid: 19174, tid: 19174, name: .atheer.airflow  >>> com.atheer.airflow <<<
10-19 15:57:42.985 19268-19268/? A/DEBUG: signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 2 (SEGV_ACCERR), fault addr 0xdeadb00c
10-19 15:57:42.990 19268-19268/? A/DEBUG: Abort message: 'Assert (/Users/heliosalonso/github/helios175/conceal/first-party/fbjni/native/fb/jni/Exceptions.cpp:308): ptr'
10-19 15:57:42.990 19268-19268/? A/DEBUG:     r0 0000006d  r1 00000000  r2 00000000  r3 deadb00c
10-19 15:57:42.990 19268-19268/? A/DEBUG:     r4 cebe1098  r5 fff40824  r6 fff40820  r7 f0d09008
10-19 15:57:42.990 19268-19268/? A/DEBUG:     r8 fff40824  r9 f0705900  sl 00000000  fp fff408fc
10-19 15:57:42.990 19268-19268/? A/DEBUG:     ip f30d8c74  sp fff407d0  lr ceba7e6b  pc ceba7e6e  cpsr 600f0030
10-19 15:57:42.992 19268-19268/? A/DEBUG: backtrace:
10-19 15:57:42.992 19268-19268/? A/DEBUG:     #00 pc 00009e6e  /data/app/com.atheer.airflow-1/lib/arm/libfb.so (_ZN8facebook14assertInternalEPKcz+69)
10-19 15:57:42.992 19268-19268/? A/DEBUG:     #01 pc 0000b6df  /data/app/com.atheer.airflow-1/lib/arm/libfb.so (_ZN8facebook3jni31getJavaExceptionForCppExceptionENSt15__exception_ptr13exception_ptrE+42)
10-19 15:57:42.992 19268-19268/? A/DEBUG:     #02 pc 0000b77f  /data/app/com.atheer.airflow-1/lib/arm/libfb.so (_ZN8facebook3jni43translatePendingCppExceptionToJavaExceptionEv+26)
10-19 15:57:42.992 19268-19268/? A/DEBUG:     #03 pc 0000dcdd  /data/app/com.atheer.airflow-1/lib/arm/libconcealjni.so
10-19 15:57:42.992 19268-19268/? A/DEBUG:     #04 pc 013680e5  /data/app/com.atheer.airflow-1/oat/arm/base.odex (offset 0x12f4000)
```

Is there a way I can catch that exception on the Android side?

Digging into their code it seems that they try to send an android exception but it crashes at the first line.

```
#ifndef FBJNI_NO_EXCEPTION_PTR
local_ref<JThrowable> getJavaExceptionForCppException(std::exception_ptr ptr) {
  FBASSERT(ptr);  <------- CRASHES OVER HERE
  local_ref<JThrowable> previous;
  auto func = [&previous] (std::exception_ptr ptr) {
    auto current = convertCppExceptionToJavaException(ptr);
    if (previous) {
      current->initCause(previous);
    }
    previous = current;
  };
  denest(func, ptr);
  return previous;
}
#endif
```

Answer (score 0):

I did follow the logic and it seems that only on release sometimes the library fails to load.
So after a lot of digging and testing it turns out that the current solution for my problem is to add to the release proguard file `-keep class com.facebook.** { *; }`. More about it over [here](https://github.com/facebook/conceal/issues/182).